# Cannot add PPA deadsnakes to ubuntu 18.04 behind company proxy

Tags: apt, 18.04, ppa, proxy

When I try to add ppa repository to Ubuntu within my company network

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

I get

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~deadsnakes/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~deadsnakes' user or team does not exist
```

the same command works outside the company network so I suppose it is a matter of proxy settings. For apt get I set up a config file with

```
Acquire {
  HTTP::proxy "http://123.456.789.10:81/";
  HTTPS::proxy "http://123.456.789.10:81/";
}
```

and with that all the sudo apt install work also within the company network.

Following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75557686/cannot-add-ppa-deadsnakes-to-ubuntu-18-04-behind-company-proxy  I tried: sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates set up an environment variable with export HTTPS_PROXY=http://@123.456.789.10:81 then run `sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:ppaname/ppa` but I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively just put the following two lines in a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` such as `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes.list`

```
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic main 
deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
```

Then add the gpg key.

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys F23C5A6CF475977595C89F51BA6932366A755776
```

Comment: apt-key adv ... returns gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data